# Examples using Google App Engine as the back-end for an Android app

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, cloud

This isn't really a direct coding question.

I am currently trying to change from Parse.com to Google App Engine as the server back-end for an android app I am working on. Using Google App Engine, I am able to do the basics of query/inserting data to an online database. I am looking for resources/examples on how to do some form of cloud code, essentially where my application calls cloud code that I myself write, which then performs actions on the database. Can anyone point me to a resources, examples, or an open source android project that uses this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google already provides a complete sample application "Mobile Backend Starter", you can use that sample app to get insights about the implementation and workflow.

https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a ["starter kit"](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/) and you can always make plain HTTP requests with HttpClient or using [AsyncHTTP](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/).

Nevertheless if you are migrating out of Parse and you want to write server-side logic easily maybe you are interested in [Backbeam](http://backbeam.io) (disclaimer: I work there). You can write server-side logic without the need to re-deploy all the time and using it from your Android code [is very easy](http://backbeam.io/documentation-android#requesting-controllers).

Backbeam is similar to Parse but maybe you are interested because we are going to release an Open Source version this year. If you have further questions we will be glad to assist you :)